# Got error after submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Form_Ajax.php =>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Testing_Ajax.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="myjquery.js"></script>

<style>

    .cls_display{

        background-color: green;

    }

</style>



<form name="nm_form" method="POST" action="Display_Ajax.php">

    <table>     

        <tr><td>User Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="nm_username" id="id_username"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" name="nm_password" id="id_password"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="button" value="Submitrunajax" onclick="runAjax()"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="button" class="cls_post" value="Submitjqueryajax"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type="submit" class="cls_post" value="SubmitPOST"/></td></tr>

    </table>

    <div id="id_display" class="cls_display">



    </div>

</form>
```

Display_Ajax.php =>

```
<?php



class Display_Ajax{

    public function __construct(){



    }

    public function printall(){

        $var_username=$_POST["nm_username"];

        $var_password=$_POST["nm_password"];

        echo $var_username.'<br>';

        echo $var_password.'<br>';

    }

}



$var_obj=new Display_Ajax();

$var_obj->printall();

?>
```

myjquery.js =>

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").addClass('cls_display');



    $("input.cls_post").click(function(){

        var temp1,temp2;

        temp1=$("#id_username").val();

        temp2=$("#id_password").val();

        /*

        $.post("Display_Ajax.php",{nm_username: temp1, nm_password: temp2},function(prm){

            alert(prm);

            $("div.cls_display").html(prm);

        });

        */

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "Display_Ajax.php",

            data: "nm_username="+temp1+"&"+"nm_password="+temp2,

            success: function(prm){

                alert(prm);

                $("div.cls_display").html(prm);

            }

        });     



    });



});
```

http://localhost/Form_Ajax.php , clicking the third submit button i got the value.

```
<tr><td><input type="submit" class="cls_post" value="SubmitPOST"/></td></tr>
```

But from Firefox>Tools>Error Console i got error =>

```
Firebug's log limit has been reached. 0 entries not shown.      Preferences  
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders]" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/jquery-1.5.js :: anonymous :: line 7207" data: no]
```

Comment: My intuition here is that the problem is in the fact that you have 2 echo statements in your printAll method, when in fact you should only have 1.

Comment: Not sure what you're problem is from this, but that message points to something wrong in JavaScript world and not PHP... tho what you have posted looks fine... possibly something in Testing_Ajax.js is breaking?

Comment: It's a Javascript error, so removing PHP from the tag list+title. PHP cannot trigger a firebug error like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your data area from:

```
data:"nm_username="+temp1+"&"+"nm_password="+temp2
```

to:

```
data: {nm_username : temp1,nm_password : temp2},
```

See if that works.

Read down on this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/